# What is represented by the content of FILE*

Tags: c, linux, unix, file-descriptor

I have this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("/Users/user/a.cc", "rb");
    printf("%i\n", f);  // 1976385616
    printf("%i\n", *f);  // 1976385768

    int sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("%i\n", sockfd);  // 4

    fclose(f);
    close(sockfd);

    int fd = open("/Users/user/a.cc", O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0);
    printf("%i\n", (int) fd); // 3
    close(fd);
}
```

I know that `3` and `4` represents the file descriptors with 0, 1, 2 being `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` respectively. Obviously `fopen` doesn't use a file descriptor.

What does the value of `FILE*` represent? How does `fopen` if not with file descriptors?

Comment: The C standard only states that `FILE`: `...is an object type capable of recording all the information needed to control a
stream, including its file position indicator, a pointer to its associated buffer (if any), an
error indicator that records whether a read/write error has occurred, and an end-of-file
indicator that records whether the end of the file has been reached;`. An implementation need to provide any details about this, in fact I think some compilers implement `FILE` as an "opaque type", meaning you can't know what's inside it.

Comment: @Lundin This is a good answer, I think you should post it as such.

Comment: @Myst No I don't think it answers the question, which was about file descriptors. I don't know much of the internals of stdio.h in Linux, so I'll refrain from posting an answer.

Comment: @Myst he prolly does not want to because of the hundreds of dups of this question.

Comment: @MartinJames Dupes, really? No that's not why. Seems like a sensible enough question to me.

Comment: @Lundin yes, there are dups:(   No, I'm not going hunting either:)

Comment: [What do FILE struct members mean exactly in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29768610/995714), [What exactly is the FILE keyword in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5672746/995714), [I Wanna know the Internal Members of struct FILE, the latest ones](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17209087/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the value of FILE* represent?

It is a pointer to `FILE` structure, for glibc its definition is [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/libio.h;h=efd09f120b49a7cdeef11baba8bce8d4e94215db;hb=HEAD#l241). Which, among other things, contains the file descriptor. You can get the file descriptor from `FILE*` using POSIX [`fileno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fileno.html) function.

For more details you may like having a look into [Interaction of File Descriptors and Standard I/O Streams](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_05.html#tag_02_05_01).