# C++ STL and multiple definitions

Tags: c++, header, definition

While searching the doc on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/), I've seen that some features are defined multiple times in different headers...

For example: `std::move` (in `<algorithm>` and `<utility>`), `std::size_t`, etc (see below).

[The page about `std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) starts with this precision:

> ```
> Defined in header <cstddef>
> Defined in header <cstdio>
> Defined in header <cstdlib>
> Defined in header <cstring>
> Defined in header <ctime>
> Defined in header <cuchar>                (since C++17)
> Defined in header <cwchar>
> ```

Why is this the case? And which header should one choose rather than any other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every standard library header needs to be self contained. If we want to use it, we are not to be forced into including anything else. Since all of the headers in the list you cite end up using `size_t` in some capacity, including them must also make `size_t` available. So it's standard mandated behavior.

Mind you, that the wording in cppreference is a bit misleading. It's not that every header always defines the type alias. It's more than likely that the actual definition is in some internal implementation specific header, that all of those public headers include it themselves.

So the behavior in essence, is that there is only ever *one* "true" definition of `size_t`. And you can get it by including any of the above headers.

As for which one to choose? You can examine the synopsis of each header. If all you need is `size_t` then `cstddef` is the most minimal header that includes it.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvate, but I'd like to let you know that I would have upvoted your answer!
Thank a lot, really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this the case?

2 reasons I can think of.

1. The function declarations and anything else in the headers use `size_t` and therefore need to declare it (same with any other thing).
2. (Maybe) Convenience. `size_t` for example is used in a lot of cases so it's simpler to have `size_t` just from including, for example `<iostream>` rather than having to include `<cstddef>` too.

> And which header should one choose rather than any other?

It appears someone else had the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594569/which-header-should-i-include-for-size-t). Though I'd say take advantage of `size_t` being in multiple headers. If you only need `<iostream>` for a program, no need to include `<cstddef>` as well just for the sake of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it helps! I don't have enough reputation to upvote, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply add #include<bits/stdc++.h> that will import all the necessary libraries for you, But sometimes it is not advisable to include all the libraries then you have to include specific libraries.

Comment: Is that a standard header?

Comment: [It's *never* advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Yeah, most of the time it is not advisable just like not to add using namespace std but if someone is doing competitive coding it is advisable to just put this library to avoid wasting any time.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, also it's not a standard header

Comment: @Surt -- no. It comes from one specific compiler.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood -- if you're going to recommend compiler-specific approaches to problems you should say that that's the case.