# I want to know the OCIStmt struct

Tags: c, oracle-call-interface

==ociap.h ==

```
sword   OCIStmtPrepare   (OCIStmt *stmtp, OCIError *errhp, const OraText *stmt,
                          ub4 stmt_len, ub4 language, ub4 mode);
```

Could you tell the `OCIStmt` struct definition of the above parameters?
Information that can not be disclosed?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: Which headers are you including to be able to use that?

Comment: Why do you need that? You should never manipulate those directly, always go through the OCI functions.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the function declaration you show only accepts *pointers* to the structures, they are likely opaque types (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type).  That is, the way the structure is defined is an implementation detail that may change from version to version or across different systems.

It would make sense to not worry about HOW it's implemented so much as understanding WHAT the functions provided do.  Remember, since the OCI functions accept pointers, they may be able to change the data contained in the structure.

A similar example of this is the *FILE* type in C (see [What exactly is the FILE keyword in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672746/what-exactly-is-the-file-keyword-in-c)).