# Printing various FILE info

Tags: c

Are there various print formatters for the file object? For example:

```
// pass the filepath
char * filepath = argv[1];
FILE * file = fopen(filepath, "r");
printf("Filepath: %s\n", file.size);
```

Error message:

```
main4.c:416:32: error: no member named 'size' in 'struct __sFILE'
```

What are the various items that can be printed from the struct?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5672746/3049655). Also, use `ftell` if you want to get the size of the file

Comment: @Spikatrix: As far as the C standard is concerned, `ftell` cannot reliably get the size of a file. Since you can't do it portably, you might as well use non-portable functions like `stat` and `fstat` (or whatever the Windows equivalents are).

Comment: That code shouldn't have produced that error message. Your `file` object is a pointer, not a structure. `file->size` rather than `file.size` could have produced that error.

Comment: Here's the full list of things that can be printed:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get various information, You can use `stat` , `lstat` which populate the `struct stat`:

```
           struct stat {
               dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
               ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
               mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
               nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
               uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
               gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
               dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
               off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
               blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
               blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
               time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
               time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
               time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
           };
```

[man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)

[man page + example](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat)

Comment: How would I use that within a c program?

Comment: @FI-Info , Please see the updated answer with the second link, it contains a detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use stat():

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html

or there are always the Win32 funcs such as GetFileSize if you want to target windows.