# How to read from pipe into a file?

Tags: c, io, pipe

I would like to read from the pipe straight into a file with the code below. base_fd is a pipe.

```
FILE* fp = fopen("dec_data", "wb+"); 
int r_result; 
int len = msg_length-part-3;  //set to 75933
while ((r_result = read(base_fd[0], fp, len))) {
       printf("r_result: %d \n", r_result);
       len -= r_result; 
       }
```

The read seems to happen fine, with r_result showing 65536 and then 10397 as required. However, when I inspect the file I created, it has a size of 0 bytes...

Comment: printf directs output to stdout.  I think you're looking for fprintf

Comment: The printf is just for error checking. The read call is supposed to write the file, or at least that was the aim

Comment: oh... missed that.  Not sure you can use a file pointer as a buffer.  You're probably telling C to put the content you read into the address where the file pointer is stored.

Comment: The second argument to `read()` should be a pointer to a buffer that will hold the data you're reading.   A `FILE *` is not going to work there.  You need to `read()` into a buffer, then `write()` from the buffer to the file.

Comment: Unfortunate, but makes sense. Thank you.
What is interesting is that no errors are thrown up - the program permits the operation.

Comment: The second arg of read is `void *` meaning you can throw any pointer in there, regardless whether it does anything sensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semantic error in your code. 
Take a look at the [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) system call signature:

```
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

The second parameter to the function is a `void` pointer (`void *buf`), which is where `read` will store the `count` bytes it reads from `fd` descriptor.

However, a `FILE *` is an abstraction of the `C library`. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672746/what-exactly-is-the-file-keyword-in-c) you can see more of it. The `struct FILE` in MinGW32 5.1.4 is:

```
typedef struct _iobuf
{
    char*   _ptr;
    int _cnt;
    char*   _base;
    int _flag;
    int _file;
    int _charbuf;
    int _bufsiz;
    char*   _tmpfname;
} FILE;
```

What read will do is similar to how we copy strings. Consider this function:

```
void strcpy(char *dst, char *src)
{
    while(*src) *dst++ = *src++;
}
```

This function will copy the contents from `src` into `dst` until it finds a `NULL` terminating byte. This is obviously a very *flawed* function and should never be used, but illustrates why your example doesn't work.

Under the hood, what `read` is doing is very similar to this `strcpy` function: it is overwriting a lot of bytes in memory starting at the address pointed to by the `fp` pointer. You are effectively losing your reference to the `FILE *` pointer and the resources associated to it.

*I'll bet that if you try to `close(fp)` after that loop you'll get a segmentation fault (it's Undefined Behavior, but I'll bet anyway).*

The right way to do what you want is:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("dec_data", "wb+"); 
char *buf;
int r_result; 
int len = msg_length - part - 3;  //set to 75933

buf = malloc(len);
if(!buf) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while ((r_result = read(base_fd[0], buf, len))) {
    fprintf(fp, buf);
    len -= r_result; 
}

free(buf);
close(fp); // now it closes the file pointer
```

Comment: If we could access the internals of struct _iobuf, perhaps the char * _ptr or base, maybe it would work if we had a read(base_fd[0], fp->_ptr, len)

Comment: @Cheetaiean Probably not. The standard library buffers the IO, so it keeps track of how much it writes/reads from/to the file. If you write directly to the pointer you won't update housekeeping data, which will case the lib to fail anyway. If you really need to read directly into another file _using a pointer_, maybe [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) helps you.